# PnP-JS-Core Property bags

Tags: sharepoint-online, web, pnp, property-bag, pnp-js-core

Is there a way to get the property bags using PnP-JS-Core?
There is nothing about it in the documentation or blogs that I've found in google.

Using REST the call is: http://sitecollection/site/_api/web/allProperties

Since PnP-JS-Core is based on REST calls I would think there is a way.

Somebody knows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use it as below in typescript:

```
pnp.Web(this.url).select("Title", "AllProperties").expand("AllProperties").get().then(r =>{    
    console.log(r);
});
```

So pure javascript would be as below:

```
$pnp.sp.web.select("AllProperties").expand("AllProperties").get().then(function(result){  
    // Select the AllProperties from the result
    console.log(result["AllProperties"].MyVarInThePropertyBag);
});
```

Result is as below in console

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Gautam, I got in the right direction with your answer. I'm editing your answer in pure javascript in case somebody else has the same doubt